# Symfony 3.3 - where should I put CSS and JS files?

Tags: javascript, php, css, symfony, psr-2

[THIS](https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html) link suggests that `/app` directory contains all configuration, templates (`.html.twig` files) and translations, and the `/src` directory contains PHP code.

However, [HERE](https://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files) we can see that .css and .js files are loaded from `/src/AppBundle/Resources/public` directory and not `/app/Resources/public` directory. What is the best practice? How should I professionaly approach this problem, and where should I keep all the templates, `.js` and `.css` files?

Comment: u can keep all the css and js in `web` folder.

Comment: I am using assetic for assets management, and the question is about best practices and the proffesional approach.

Comment: There is no single answer. Most of this will come down to personal experience / preference.

Comment: so what's the problèm of using the assetic mangment !! 
you can use assetic and just set your stylesheets and js files under web/app/css
web/app/js

Comment: Well, if you are following modular approach which I think is a best practice, it gives you cleaner code and it helps implements single responsibility principle, you would put your assets in `/src/AppBundle/Resources/public` every bundle should be independent and have its own assets, which makes it easier to reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to put css and javascript that serve for general purposes in `/app/Resources/public` and the ones specific to the concerned bundle in `/src/YourBundleNameBundle/Resources/public`. Like that when I want to see a code specific for a bundle I will just go to that bundle , when it's a general purpose code I would be sure that it's in the root. I have seen expert people doing it and it makes sense for me.

It's a matter of choice and there is no right and wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is to put your css and js files in your bundle particularly in folder that you called "public" (yourBundle/Ressources/public/css/yourStyle.css)
and make sure to run this command before

```
php bin/console assets:install
```

and To avoid typing this command each time, I recommend you make a link (a kind of shortcut), by adding the active parameter:

```
assets:install --symlink
```

So, the web /bundles/folderBundle actually points to src/yourBundle/Resources/public

On Windows, you must run the command prompt in administrator mode